# Float formatting on SQL insert using dict

Tags: python, sql, dictionary, sql-insert, postgresql-9.5

i try to insert values from a dictionary to a postgres DB via SQL Insert Statement.

Host Language is Python.

First i only used VARCHAR Datytype and transformed the values like this

```
insert_query = 'INSERT INTO tweets VALUES (%s, %s)'
    for tweet in tweets:
        engine.execute(insert_query, (tweet['username'], tweet['text'])
```

In the next step i also need numeric values for "followers_count" (e.g. 2345) and "sentiment_score" (e.g. 0.654)

Is there something like %f (for transform to float) or another way to do this properly?

Comment: Try `%f` in the insert statement, or control the precision like `%.2f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert_query = 'INSERT INTO tweets VALUES (%s, %s, %f, %.2f)'
for tweet in tweets:
    engine.execute(insert_query, (tweet['username'], tweet['text'], tweet['floatval'], tweet['double_decimal_floatval'])
```